# Git on server with nginx

Tags: git, http, nginx

I was looking for manual how to **set up git on server with nginx** and I haven't found it.

I've logged in to server by ssh with root user, installed git-core and created a bare repo. Whats next? How to make this special **http** link to this repo to connect to repo from many computers and make clone to start working?

Comment: do you need to access the repo via http(s)? if there is no real need for this, i'd suggest to just use ssh to access it. that way you can init the bare repo as user and do everything else as normal user. no root, no webserver required. just git, local files, and ssh.

Comment: i found the way how to connect to repo from other computers: `git clone root@mydomen.com:/link/to/my_project.git`. But the main problem is that I cant create this special link (ssh is ok too) like _ssh://mydomen.com/git/project.git_. And when I do commands like `git push` or `git fetch` it asks me the password. How to set up this special link.

Comment: a) what should it do instead of asking for a password? do you want to store the password? have you tried public key crypto? b) what do you mean with special link? why is "root@mydomen.com:/link/to/my_project.git" not a special link? what would your special link allow?

Comment: **a)** no i haven't tried public key crypto. as i know i should create it for everyone who's working on project? **b)** Special link like **ssh://mydomen.com/git/project.git**. After it is created people will use it like that `clone ssh://mydomen.com/git/project.git` and use just one password ones.

Comment: like in "allow many users without local unix accounts to use the git repository in read/write mode, where the repo is served over https with a shared password and your webserver is nginx"?

Comment: @mnagel yes) exactly. that's what i'm looking for

Answer (score -1):

You need a web frontend for git.

Have a look at https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/InterfacesFrontendsAndTools#Web_Interfaces for an overview

Comment: web interfaces are UIs for git, not a method of making the repository available (which seems to be what he wants)